# Creating a custom option in jdl

Tags: jhipster, jdl

My question here is flashing in my mind,how to create a custom option in jdl file?
My use case is to add a pipeline like this
pipeline : [Jenkins,Azure,Gitlab,Travis]

And I know that there is a command present in jhipster ci-cd with a specific application.
But if I use hundreds of microfrontends, hitting command jhipster ci-cd one by one is a tedious job obviously.
So my question is jhipster supports to create a custom option in jdl file?

Comment: I asked the creator of JDL, and here is his response: As far as I know, there's no built-in way to have a custom option in the JDL. That would mean driving the code generation from a custom option, and it's quite some work.

Comment: Thank you for your kind response @Matt Riable

Answer (score 1):

`ci-cd` is not currently integrated in the app generation process.
In my opinion we can integrate.

There is not way to customize JDL but a lot has changed recently. And maybe a blueprint can customize it later this year.

To add an new JDL option to application is much easier now: see [Message Broker](https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/blob/main/generators/server/options/message-broker.mts) and [Database Migration](https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/blob/main/generators/server/options/database-migration.mts) options.